# Influence of Normalization and PCA on Distance Metrics

Tags: pca, data-transformation, k-nearest-neighbour, c++

After standardizing my dataset, I perform a principal component analysis. Then I do a nearest neighbour search.

I observed then after performing the PCA, even though I kept (for testing purposes) all resulting dimensions (so the input dataset has the same number of features as the PCA-transformed one), my nearest neighbour results drop.

As a distance metric in the nearest neighbour search I use the cosine distance. My intuitive assumption was, that this distant metric should not be influenced by the PCA in the case I don't reduce the dimensionality of my dataset.

How can the performance drop be explained? Did I probably do something wrong?

Here is how I perform the PCA. I use Eigen and C++. `traindata` is my untouched input dataset where each row is a sample and each column a feature:

```
  // Mean centering data.
  featureMeans = traindata.colwise().mean();
  Eigen::MatrixXf centered = traindata.rowwise() - featureMeans;
  // Compute featurewise standard deviations.
  Eigen::MatrixXf cov = centered.adjoint() * centered;
  Eigen::VectorXf variances = cov.diagonal();
  stdDevs = variances.cwiseSqrt();
  // Normalize each feature with standard deviation.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < centered.rows(); i++) {
    centered.row(i) = centered.row(i).array() / stdDevs.array().transpose();
  }

  // Compute SVD.
  Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXf> svd(centered, Eigen::ComputeThinV);
  // Transformation matrix.
  pcaTransform = svd.matrixV();
  // Project the dataset.
  traindata = centered * pcaTransform;
```

And later when I get a new datapoint, I transform it in the space of the principal components like this:

```
Eigen::VectorXf NearestNeighbour::transform(Eigen::VectorXf& vec) {
  vec -= featureMeans;
  vec = vec.array() / stdDevs.array();
  vec = vec.transpose() * pcaTransform;
  return vec;
}
```

Then in the nearest neighbour algorithm I compute the cosine similarity like this:

```
float NearestNeighbour::calcCosineSimilarity(Eigen::VectorXf& vecOne, Eigen::VectorXf& vecTwo) {
  float dot = vecOne.dot(vecTwo);
  float cosine = dot / (vecOne.norm() * vecTwo.norm());
  return cosine;
}
```

I wrote a test script in python using my dataset. The input vector is randomly created as I only wanted to test the concept:

```
inpvec = [[ 0.73977109,  0.03620438,  0.25417753,  0.11561778,  0.82897718,
         0.13585422,  0.16245644,  0.97201561,  0.68201026,  0.52702283,
         0.21245685,  0.246901  ,  0.72042289,  0.52233973,  0.89980493,
         0.3394559 ,  0.92817351,  0.64084039,  0.73594745,  0.825488  ,
         0.87527608,  0.02777485,  0.30630228,  0.26867405,  0.10130528,
         0.43129711,  0.41076364,  0.22625131,  0.2616146 ,  0.52088176,
         0.23174206,  0.1674724 ,  0.81184377,  0.68945395,  0.12719359,
         0.97440578,  0.18162815,  0.29054626,  0.22535362,  0.44556911,
         0.15830425,  0.15641608,  0.00425475,  0.77260893,  0.84462181,
         0.98222192,  0.12986739,  0.16809029,  0.58549871,  0.38430837,
         0.39776035,  0.76900314]]


def loadTrainingData(path):
  f = open(path)
  tData = []
  for line in f:
    lsplit = line.split(",")
    datapoint = []
    for feature in lsplit:
      datapoint.append(float(feature))

    tData.append(datapoint)
  data = np.array(tData) 
  X = np.delete(data, data.shape[1] - 1, 1) # Strip class.
  return X


inpvec = np.array(inpvec)
X = loadTrainingData("trainingfile.csv")


normalizer = Normalizer()
X_norm = normalizer.fit_transform(X)
cosdists = []
for datapoint in X_norm:
  cosdists.append(cosine(normalizer.transform(inpvec)[0], datapoint))
value = min(cosdists)
index = [i for i, j in enumerate(cosdists) if j == value]
print "min dist at " + str(index) + " with " + str(value)


# PCA
pipeline = Pipeline([('scaling', StandardScaler()), ('pca', PCA(n_components=X.shape[1]))])
X_reduced = pipeline.fit_transform(X)

inpVecReduced = pipeline.transform(inpvec)[0]
cosdistsTwo = []
for datapointPCA in X_reduced:
  cosdistsTwo.append(cosine(inpVecReduced, datapointPCA))
valuePCA = min(cosdistsTwo)
indexPCA = [i for i, j in enumerate(cosdistsTwo) if j == valuePCA]
print "min dist at " + str(indexPCA) + " with " + str(valuePCA)
```

The output of this is:

```
min dist at [462] with 0.322760977886
min dist at [304] with 0.461332258519
```

My assumption was that it should output the same index in both cases. Why is this happening?

Comment: Was there a performance drop? Can you add more information about what you did & what happened?

Comment: I compute the nearest neighbour compared to a dataset based on cosine similarity. After I perform the pca my algorithm finds different datapoints as the the nearest neighbour.

Comment: In your Python code, what is matrix `t`? It is certainly not a rotation matrix, so why would the angles be preserved?

Comment: You're right, that was my mistake, it's not orthogonal vectors. I get rid of it as it only adds confusion. I exchange it with another example which also didn't work out.

Comment: If you use a rotation (i.e. orthogonal) matrix, is *has to* work out.

Comment: Re your new Python script. Isn't the difference in how `inpvec` is transformed prior to computing angles? I'm not sure what  `pipeline.transform` does exactly, but I assume it will center and scale `inpvec` using training data mean and variances. When you compute it manually, you don't seem to do either, or am I missing it?

Comment: First, I just noticed I made in the normalized version the mistake to not transform the input vector. I changed it in the code, but the results are still the same. I think what @ryan mentioned is the reason. Because when in the version without PCA use standardization, the results are equivalent. And just as a sidenote, the pipeline applies fit_transform for the Standardizer and the PCA one after antoher.

Comment: In your python code that I can see right now you seem to be normalizing both training X and the `inpvec` both with and without PCA. I don't understand why the results disagree. They should agree. What do you mean that `when in the version without PCA use standardization, the results are equivalent`? Your current Python code does use standardization in the no-PCA computation; do the results agree or not?

Comment: No, once i normalizie and in the pca version I standardize. But when I also use Standardizer() for the non-pca too, the results agree. Check @ryans answer.

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't realize that `Normalizer()` does not standardize (i.e. does not divide by standard deviations). The word "normalize" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCA is a linear transformation, and if you are keeping every dimension, then your data should have the same distance function.  Supposing that your original data was some matrix $X$ and your resulting data is some transformed matrix $Y = AX$, then the distance should be unchanged:

$$ d(y_i, y_j) = d(A x_i, A x_j) $$

and if you are using the cosine distance,

$$ d(A x_i, A x_j) = 1 - ((A x_i)^T (A x_j)) / (\|A x_i\| \| A x_j \|) $$

and since the $\| A x_i \| = \| x_i \|$,

$$ = 1 - (x_i^T A^T A x_j) / (\| x_i \| \| x_j \|) $$

and since $A^T A = I$,

$$ = 1 - (x_i^T x_j) / (\| x_i \| \| x_j \|) = d(x_i, x_j) $$

so all this was a very roundabout way to say that distance calculations should not be affected.

*Edit, once code appeared:* in the calculation of `centered`, you are normalizing the features for unit variance.  This might be a good idea in general, but it's going to change the distances between points since essentially you are weighting some dimensions to be more or less important than others.  In that case, your resulting data is some transformed matrix $Y = ANX$ where $A$ is some orthogonal basis (so $A^T A = I$ as before), but $N$ is just a diagonal matrix that is not necessarily $I$.  In that case you can't show that $d(y_i, y_j) = d(x_i, x_j)$.  However, you can show that $d(y_i, y_j) = d(N x_i, N x_j)$.  That means that if you were to transform your input data to have unit variance in each dimension, then the distance would be the same as the post-PCA data.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I made some mistake in the actual transformation step. If I have a clue but aren't sure I might add it to the question. For now I accept your answer :).

Comment: Yeah, I can't help point out what the issue might be unless there's some code, unfortunately.

Comment: Added some code.

Comment: In accordance, I've added an update to my answer.

Comment: You found it. I was not quite aware of how the standardization influences the relative differences. Seems it's the cause of the performance drop.

For my understanding: when a feature had a small standard deviation it's values scaled higher and thus gets more important / contributes more to the distance measurement and vice versa or?

Would it be a good idea to just normalize and mean center all my data (scale to [0, 1] and then move mean to 0) before performing the pca? Then everything should work or? I think there is no standard answer on how to scale prior to pca.

Comment: You're right, there is no standard answer.  I don't understand what you're doing well enough to provide any advice here.  If you're doing PCA before nearest neighbor classification (or some other classifier), the typical use (at least in my world) would be for dimensionality reduction.  In your code here, you keep all the dimensions.  If you dropped the irrelevant dimensions with small eigenvalues, and worked in a lower-dimensional space, this might boost the accuracy of your classifier.  But of course, the pairwise distances between points are going to be different if you do that.

Comment: I will do that. My question was more academic and to verify my pca works correctly.
Can pure pca lead to performance boosts in nearest neighbour? I had the impression dropping dimensions leads to worse outcomes. Wouldn't dimensions with a small variance anyway have only a small impact on distance measures?
Also one more thing: can the feature mean centering have an impact on the performance? I observed that but thought it also shouldn't change distances really.

Comment: As always the answer is "it depends".  Suppose you have an easily linearly separable dataset in a few dimensions, then add a bunch of dimensions of low-magnitude noise.  These noise dimensions will skew the nearest neighbor distances, and may reduce performance for the nearest neighbor classifier.  Applying PCA would get rid of the low-magnitude noise dimensions, fixing the problem.  The key is that even though the noise dimensions are noise, there may be many dimensions, so the impact on distance can end up larger.  Feature mean centering doesn't affect distances; just the variance scaling.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing to add, I realised that my nearest neighbour performance was affect by mean centering (no pca involved in that test). In version A, I just normalized between [0, 1]. In Version B I did the same and then mean centered. The results werde different (worse, with cosine distance metric). Do you know why? And do you know why for pca mean centering is nessecary? Sorry for all the questions ;)

Comment: I realised why. The computed means from my dataset do not represent the true means but just my best guess. So subtracting them from new datapoints in the evaluation step can influence the outcome / distances from new datapoints to my trainingdata. But not the distances within the trainingdata. If I would know the "true" mean for each feature, this would not happen.